# Flutter stuck with a "DatabaseEvent subtype" error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, stream, flutter-streambuilder

The below code gives an error of subtype

[***Data Structure***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEA66.png)

**code**

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: _database.orderByKey().onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final valudisp = <Card>[];
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final firstdata = snapshot.data! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            firstdata.forEach((key, value) {
              final datalast = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
              final coinname = datalast.keys;
              final displaycard = Card(...);
              valudisp.add(displaycard);
             });
          }
          return Expanded(...);
       }); 
      }
```

**Now I'm getting below error**

```
type 'DatabaseEvent' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>' in typecast
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: error: The getter 'snapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Event'.

Comment: I have an error in Second Snapshot. my database like as an attached image.

Comment: Try `final firstdata = snapshot.data! as Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: it's work, but now i'm getting below error on App
type 'DatabaseEvent' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String,dynamic>' in type cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine.

map the first snapshot as <Object, dynamic>.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: _database.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final valudisp = <Card>[];
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final firstdata = (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent)
                .snapshot
                .value as Map<Object?, dynamic?>;
            firstdata.forEach((key, value) {
              final datalast = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
              final coinname = datalast['namedata'];
              final _diff = datalast['dif'];
              final time = datalast['Time'];
              final Quantity = datalast['Quantity'];
              final tradep = datalast['tradep'];
              final displaycard =Card(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`DatabaseEvent` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseEvent-class.html) there:

```
(snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                 //
```